# Include graphic only in debug build?

Tags: iphone, ios, build

Is there a simple way to make sure a resource isn't included in the release build of my app using the Configuration switch?

It's never used in the release build, but given it's nature I'd prefer to not even include it. Including an image commonly used to represent software bugs seems like store rejection bait.

Clarification: I know how to not use the image in the application. What I want to do is make sure the image isn't even in the .app bundle when I build for the release configuration. I don't want an App Store reviewer browsing the bundle and saying "Hey! A bug icon! How can I get that to show? Since I can't figure it out, there must be some secret functionality."

Comment: I'm not a super-script guy, but you could include a script that either copies, or does not copy the image to the .app based on the debug settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Worst case, add a Run Script Build Phase to your target:

```
if [ $BUILD_STYLE = "Release" ]; then
    rm "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/debug.png"
fi
```

Comment: Worst-Case?  This sounds like best-case to me.

Comment: You probably should use `$CONFIGURATION` rather than `$BUILD_STYLE`.

Comment: Also, you can use `$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH` instead of `MyApp.app/Contents/Resources`. Among other things, this lets the script adapt if you change the product name, and it lets you reuse the script in different targets (possibly as a separate script file).

Comment: I ended up using `$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH`. The idea of using a script to touch the output is what I was missing. Call it a blind spot caused by code signing terror. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way I can think of is to have two different targets in your Xcode project. Then simply don’t include the debug image in the distribution target. The headache here is that you must make sure to add new classes/assets to both targets.

One note: when building for distribution, make sure you do as hard of a clean as you can (i.e. Clean All in Xcode, remove the build directory, then close and reopen Xcode before performing the build). I’ve found that mostly-identical targets tend to not quite clear out their products between builds and sometimes assets from another target creep their way into the wrong targets.

Comment: I think you might be right. I'll accept this in a few hours if no miracle answer drops in my lap. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. rentzsch's is less maintenance, but this was a clever workaround. :)

Comment: I agree. We use the multiple-target approach to selectively include many files at a time so it works for us, but for just a few I definitely think rentzsch has it right.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a preprocessing directive to optionally use/show that image. Without going into too much detail it'd be something like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
//use the debug image
#endif
```

Then when you do a distribution build, DEBUG will not be defined and voila, your image won't be used. You can define this directive in the yourProjectName_Prefix.pch, although DEBUG builds should already have that particular macro defined.

Comment: Or you could do something like: 

`#ifdef DEBUG`
`#define myImage yourDebugImage.png`
`#else`
`#define myImage yourNonDebugImage.png`
`#endif`

and then you could just use myImage everywhere you want to display the debug/non-debug images.

Comment: Thanks, but my concern is including the image in the output .app at all. I know how to not use it. :) I've clarified the question.

Comment: I see... are you using an automated build system or creating the builds off of your machine locally?